# Why aren't my checkboxes being disabled even when I set the property 'disabled="disabled"'?

Tags: html, properties, checkbox

I have a page where I want several checkboxes to be set as disabled by default, but can be enabled via JavaScript. When I view the page source, the HTML on a checkbox looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="morning1" name="morning[]" class="morning" value="1" disabled="disabled" />
```

However, the boxes are actually enabled. What's more, when I check them in Firebug, the disabled property doesn't even show up. Any idea what's going on here? Is my initial HTML code somehow flawed?

OK, here's what my page is producing for the content of an entire table cell:

```
<span class="dayOfWeek">1</span>
<div class="cellContent"><input type="checkbox" id="allDay1" name=allDay[] class="allDay" value="1" checked="checked" /> <label for="allDay1">All Day</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="morning1" name="morning[]" class="morning" value="1" disabled="disabled" /> <label for="morning1">Morning</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="afternoon1" name="afternoon[]" class="afternoon" value="1" disabled="disabled" /> <label for="afternoon1">Afternoon</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="evening1" name="evening[]" class="evening" value="1" disabled="disabled" /> <label for="evening1">Evening</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="swingShift1" name="swingShift[]" class="swingShift" value="1" disabled="disabled" /> <label for="swingShift1">Swing Shift</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="earlyMorning1" name="earlyMorning[]" class="earlyMorning" value="1" disabled="disabled" /> <label for="earlyMorning1">Early Morning</label></div>
```

Comment: Where are you disabling your checkboxes ?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but basically, it's for requesting time off. If someone clicks "all day," they shouldn't then be able to click on any of the other shifts they want off. This is code to bring up stuff that is already in the database. If they then uncheck the all day box, the rest of the boxes for that day will be enabled.

Comment: Basically, it's on a calendar. Each day on the calendar has five checkboxes to choose from: allDay, morning, afternoon, evening, and lateNight. If they choose "all day," then the JavaScript disables the other boxes for that day to prevent redundant data being entered. The HTML code here is what shows up when a user brings up their own page and it already has data entered in that they wish to edit.

Comment: Now this is bizarre--the disabling works fine in JS Bin, but not in my page. I really don't understand what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="allDay1" 
    name=allDay[] 
    class="allDay" 
    value="1" 
    checked="checked" /> 
    <label for="allDay1">All Day</label><br />
```

None of those attributes are `disabled="disabled"`. You haven't actually added it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="allDay1" name=allDay[] class="allDay" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be checked if it's disabled. That's the whole point--to keep people from inadvertently checking something if I want it not to be checkable.

Answer (score 0):

I should give myself -1 for this. I had some JavaScript down the page that, for some reason I can't remember, was going and re-enabling anything that was disabled. What in the name of the FSM was I thinking?